# List all Distribution list with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

is it possible to list all Distribution lists with Microsoft Graph API?

I could list all group in one Tenant with:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

but I need to filter this list to get only the Distribution list which is defined in Microsoft 365 admin center.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If the group types collection contains Unified, the group is a Microsoft 365 group. Otherwise it's either a security group or distribution group. If it is mail enabled, it is a distribution group.

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("$count", "true")
};

var groups = await graphClient.Groups
    .Request( queryOptions )
    .Header("ConsistencyLevel","eventual")
    .Filter("mailEnabled eq true and NOT(groupTypes/any(s:s eq 'Unified'))")
    .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Distribution groups are only exposed in Exchange PowerShell, and they're not currently supported via the Microsoft Graph API. Being said that i remember [an existing user voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38178205-list-members-from-exchange-dynamic-distribution-gr), consider upvoting it; so that Microsoft Graph team can consider implementing it.